# How to add more controls?

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I am working on this program where people can add as many `TextBoxes` as they want but I can only add one.

Here's the code,

```
int y = 0;
string name = "textbox";
int curNumber = 10;

name = name + curNumber.ToString();

TextBox myText = new TextBox();
myText.Location = new Point(25, y);

this.Controls.Add(myText);
myText.Text = curNumber.ToString();

y += 10;
curNumber += 1;
```

Comment: Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: If 'y' and 'curNumber' are declared locally then they would all have the same name and be positioned **on top** of each other making it look like there is only one.  Best guess...move the declarations of 'y' and 'curNumber' out to Class level.

Answer (score 0):

If 'y' and 'curNumber' are declared locally then they would all have the same name and be positioned on top of each other making it look like there is only one. Best guess...move the declarations of 'y' and 'curNumber' out to Class level.